# SQL Group relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a question regarding SQL.

I have 3 tables:

- Table 1 is called `news` and has a primary key `ID`
- Table 2 is called `categories` and also has a primary key `ID`
- Table 3 is called `newscat` and has 2 columns, `news` and `cat`

I am now in search for a single SQL query that allows me to find the next ID without being in category X.

To give a practical example:

- I have a single newspage and a button to jump to the next news item.
- I do also have a group that is called `Unpublished`, so I am now trying to get the next `news` that is NOT unpublished. News can be in multiple categories!

  ```
  SELECT p.id 
  FROM posts p, post_cats pc 
  WHERE ???? 
  AND pc.post = p.id 
  AND p.id < '22' 
  ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 1
  ```

Anyone have any idea?

Hope this works (just written this by hand real quick):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `special` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL COMMENT '[unpub]',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`special`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `special`) VALUES
(1, 'Category#1', ''),
(2, 'Category#2', ''),
(3, 'Category#3', ''),
(4, 'Unpublished', 'unpub');




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `desc` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `title`, `desc`) VALUES
(1,'Title#1','Desc#1'),
(2,'Title#2','Desc#2'),
(3,'Title#3','Desc#3');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_cats` (
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `cat` (`cat`,`post`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `post_cats` (`cat`, `post`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 3),
(4, 2);
```

So the idea would be if I am on `News` 1 and click next, it should return `News` 3, because `News` 2 is in the `Category` that has the "unpub" flag set.

Comment: add test case: `create table ...` with values

Comment: Please show the layout of the tables.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you have to explicitly say what you mean by "next".

Comment: So if I wanted to do it the other Way around (Finding the next News of Group X) it would be easy `SELECT p.id FROM posts p,post_cats pc WHERE pc.cat='".$_GET['cat']."' AND pc.post=p.id AND p.id<'".$currentID."' ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 1`, but to do it the way I need it I would have to fumble around with multiple sets of Rows and I can't figure that one out.